# Django Rest Framework : How to initialise & use custom exception handler?

Tags: python, django, exception, django-rest-framework

DRF newbie here.

I'm trying to handle all exceptions within the project through a custom exception handler. Basically, what I'm trying to do is if any serializer fails to validate the data, I want to send the corresponding error messages to my custom exception handler and reformat errors accordingly.

I've added the following to **settings.py.**

```
# DECLARATIONS FOR REST FRAMEWORK
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'PAGE_SIZE': 20,
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'main.exceptions.base_exception_handler',

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
    )
}
```

But once I send an invalid parameter to any of the endpoints in the project, I still get a default error message of the DRF validator. (e.g. {u'email': [u'This field is required.']})

Errors raised on corresponding serializer's validate function, never reaches to my exception handler.

Here is an image of the [Project Tree](http://i.hizliresim.com/9o6DNN.jpg) that I'm working on.

Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

**To do that, your `base_exception_handler` should check when a [`ValidationError`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#validationerror) exception is being raised and then modify and return the custom error response.**

(**Note:**
A serializer raises `ValidationError` exception if the data parameters are invalid and then 400 status is returned.)

In `base_exception_handler`, we will check if the exception being raised is of the type `ValidationError` and then modify the errors format and return that modified errors response.

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError

def base_exception_handler(exc, context):
    # Call DRF's default exception handler first,
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    # check that a ValidationError exception is raised
    if isinstance(exc, ValidationError): 
        # here prepare the 'custom_error_response' and
        # set the custom response data on response object
        response.data = custom_error_response 

    return response
```